# .load page with form variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to load a page with variables from a form and it seems it doesn't get my select value. I'm new to JavaScript and I need this instead doing a serialize to get values and then use .load().
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include('dbconfig.php');
    $id=$_GET['id'];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function filtreaza_tip () {
                var tip = document.getElementById("tip").value;
                var id_local= document.getElementById("id_local").value;
                $( "#tipuri_rezervare" ).load("select_tip_rezervare.php?id="+id_local+"&tip="+tip);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="tip" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_local" id="id_local" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
        <select name="tip" id="tip" onchange="filtreaza_tip();">
        <option value="0">Selectati Tipul</option>
            <?php
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * 
                                       FROM Tip_Rezervare  
                                       INNER JOIN Local ON Local.ID_Local=:id_local
                                       INNER JOIN Leg_Tip_Local ON Tip_Rezervare.ID_Tip=Leg_Tip_Local.ID_Tip and Leg_Tip_Local.ID_Local=:id_local");
                $stmt->bindParam(':id_local', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute() ;
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                    $local=$row['Denumire_Local'];
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['ID_Tip'].'">'.$row['Nume'].'</option>';
                }    
                echo'</select>';        
            ?>
            <div id="tipuri_rezervare">
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a working one with serialize but I don't want that. Here is the working code:

```
function filtreaza_tip ()
{
    var datastring = $("#tip").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tip_rezervare.php",
        data: datastring,
        success: function(data) {      
             $( "#tipuri_rezervare" ).load('select_tip_rezervare.php?',data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form `id` and dropdown `id` are same.
Thats the reason you are getting the issue.
Change the ids it will work fine.

Comment: omg that's true, cant belive i didnt notice that :D, thnx alot!

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery method $.val() like that :

```
$("#tip").val(); // Return the input / select value of the selector
```

Check the jQuery Api : http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

Load uses POST method so you can just do this:

```
var tip = document.getElementById("tip").value;
var id_local= document.getElementById("id_local").value;
$( "#tipuri_rezervare" ).load("select_tip_rezervare.php, {tip: tip, id: id_local});
```

Then you can get your values on your select_tip_rezervare.php page with `$_POST['tip']` and `$_POST['id']`.

Comment: Kudos to Andolasoft for noticing that you used the id tip twice.